# What is wrong with this method using an int[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

This method is supposed to return true if there is more than one 1 in a column of a 2D array, yet it doesn't work. I can't figure out what's wrong with it so I thought I'd get some expert opinions.

Example:

```
10010
01001
10100
```

will return `true` because there are 2 ones in the first column.

Here is the code

```
public static boolean isVert(int[][] x) { //checks for more than one 1 in columns
int count = 0;
boolean break2 = false;
boolean check = false; //false means no 2 (or more) queens in same column
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
        if (x[i][j] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 1) {
            break2 = true;
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (break2) {
        break;
    }
}
return check;
```

}

Comment: A debugger would be a good place to start

Comment: Have you learned to use a debugger yet?

Comment: Is it if ANY column has 2 or more or if EACH? Your comment says "each" but your example only has 1 column with 2 or more.

Comment: You don't need two booleans... And this looks fine.

Comment: Good code for break-with-label usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You break at the first occurance of 1 in whole array, which is probably not the expected result.

Explanation of how your code works:

- loop until counter i is less than length of array (number of rows in array)
- loop until counter j is less than length of i-th row (number of columns or elements in array)
- check if element on i-th row and j-th column is 1, if true, increase variable *count* by one
- if *count* is greater than 1 (this means it has to be **2 or greater**) set *break2* and *check* to true, break
- if break2 is true (which is as *count* is > 2 and first loop breaks), break this loop too:

  - this happens in 1st row of your example table
- end of loops, return check (which is *true* because 1st row contains 2 ones)

The **problem** in your code is that you break when you find your first row that satisfies your condition, but you do not (necessarily) check all the rows in given array.

I have corrected the code for you, hopefully it works (untested)

```
public static boolean isVert(int[][] x) { //checks for more than one 1 in columns
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        int rowCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            if (x[i][j] == 1) {
                rowCount++;
            }
            if(rowCount > 1) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // returns true if count of lines containing 1 equals length of array, 
    // if not, returns false
    return count == x.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I dont get the return line though. Why was my code different? I checked if count was more than 1 then it would return true.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added an explanation on how your program works and why it doesn't work correctly. I have noticed that I have provided wrong solution, this will check if there is at least 1 one in the array, not more than one. I have corrected that.

Comment: I dont need to check all the rows, once I find a column with more than one 1, I dont need to go on any further.

Comment: Well, you've said, I quote: `more than one 1 in each column of a 2D array`

Comment: Yeah my bad, thats a mistake on my part. fixed.

Comment: If you need to check if only one *row* contains more than one element '1', you can change that break for return and it will work. You could then also remove all the other code containing the counter, which is not needed. If you wish, I can add this updated version.

Comment: That would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start of by improving your naming convention.  Your code has many variables named by their contents, instead of named by how they are used.  For example:

```
boolean check = false; // false means no two queens in the same column.
```

instead of

```
boolean twoQueensInColumn = false;
```

and the other example

```
boolean break2 = false;
```

instead of the more reasonable

```
boolean continueLooking = true;
```

Plus, it is a very good idea to avoid using variables as place holders for loop escaping logic.  For example, the two stanzas

```
  ...
    if (count > 1) {
        break2 = true;
        check = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (break2) {
    break;
}
```

are a breeding ground for bugs, requiring a lot of debugging to ensure they work "right now" which will break just as soon as you modify the code.  Much better would be

```
boolean keepLooking = false;
for (int row = 0; keepLooking && (row < board.length); row++) {
  int queensInColumn = 0;
  for (int column = 0; keepLooking && (column < board[row].length, column++) {
    if (board[row][column] != 0) {
      queensInColumn++;
    }
    if (queensInColumn > 1) {
      keepLooking = false;
    }
  }
}
```

The main difference being the control logic is in the loop "conditional" block, where it belongs.

Comment: After you change your code to be more readable, you probably will be able to read the error in your code more easily....

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend turning your integers to string and using the .contains() method and looping through that. This would make the code easier to understand.